# Session undefined error in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

I am getting undefined when i log my session object **req.session** in one of my routes . Any reason for this behavior

Below are snippets of my code any idea

```
var express =require("express");
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var expressSession = require('express-session');

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession());




 app.get("/",function(req,res)
    {

      console.log(req.session);
      res.send("Heelllo");
    })
```

Comment: try specifying a secret.  app.use(expressSession({secret: '11asd2jRtsgw5%t26'}));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide "secret" option to express-session constructor

```
var express =require("express");
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var expressSession = require('express-session');

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession({secret:'somesecrettokenhere'}));

app.get("/",function(req,res){

        console.log(req.sessionID);
        res.send("Heelllo");
})
```